# Why the insert data (value) treated as column name ? #1054 - Unknown column

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-error-1054

```
 INSERT INTO users(`username`, `password`, `location`, `aboutusr`, `gender`) 
 VALUES (`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`h`)
```

The above query returns the error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'b' in 'field list'

Comment: Apart from single quote issue, you have 5 columns in the `INSERT` and 6 values in the `VALUES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except numerical, you need to include values inside single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO users(username,password,location,aboutusr,gender)
VALUES ('b','c','d','e','f','h');
```

Comment: hmm, actualy am using it , just because it is my first time in this web site , i still dont know how to write in it properly

Comment: @ImadEddin: You are using back-ticks. There is a difference in back-ticks and single quotes. Moreover, you have mention only 5 column-names, but there are 6 values.

Comment: ' ahaaaaa (that moment when you notice how stupid ur lol ) thanks bro it worked (y)

Answer (score 0):

Just quote your chracters

```
INSERT INTO users(username,password,location,aboutusr,gender) VALUES ('b','c','d','e','f','h')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save 6 diffrent values into 5 columns. That is the issue. Try this. Hope this will help.

```
INSERT INTO users(username,password,location,aboutusr,gender) VALUES ('b','c','d','e','f')
```

Comment: your code worked fine,but why this do not work "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, location, gender,aboutusr) VALUES ($username,$password,$email,$location,$gender,$aboutusr);" . ps: am using ``

Comment: thanks it worked bro , i understand where was i wrong , i was using `` ,instead of ' ' , in values inserting :* thanks